# JPA NamedNativeQuery syntax error with Hibernate, PostgreSQL 9

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I am having a rather odd problem. I have native query which runs perfectly when executed on sql server:

```
SELECT  date_time, GREATEST(sum(count_up - count_down) OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('day', result.date_time) ORDER BY date_time),0) AS cum_amt FROM   peoplecounting.result order  BY date_time;
```

However, using this query as native query in JPA results in syntax error

```
@NamedNativeQueries({@NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "Result.getTotal",
        query = "SELECT  date_time, GREATEST(sum(count_up - count_down) OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('day', peoplecounting.result.date_time) ORDER BY date_time),0) AS cum_amt FROM   peoplecounting.result order  BY date_time;")})

public class Result implements Serializable {...
```

///

```
@Entity
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "TotalResultMapping", entities = {@EntityResult(entityClass = TotalResult.class, fields = {@FieldResult(name = "total", column = "cum_amt"), @FieldResult(name = "date", column = "date_time")})})

public class TotalResult {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public TotalResult() {
}


@Id Date date;

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public Integer getTotal() {
    return total;
}

public void setTotal(Integer total) {
    this.total = total;
}

Integer total;
```

}

When calling:  `em.createNativeQuery("Result.getTotal","TotalResultMapping").getResultList();`

I get:

```
INFO  [stdout] (default task-44) Hibernate: Result.getTotal
WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-44) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-44) Error: Syntax error at or near "Result"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was that `em.createNativeQuery(...)` was not the correct invocation of a `NamedNativeQuery` in order to do that I should've invoked em.`createNamedQuery(...)`. However, seeing that `em.createNativeQuery(...)` does not accept `@SqlResultSetMapping` it is very difficult to map the result to a custom class.

The end solution was to use

```
 return em.createNativeQuery("SELECT  peoplecounting.result.date_time, GREATEST(sum(peoplecounting.result.count_up - peoplecounting.result.count_down) " +
            "OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('day', peoplecounting.result.date_time) " +
            "ORDER BY peoplecounting.result.date_time),0) AS cum_amt" +
            " FROM   peoplecounting.result" +
            " order  BY peoplecounting.result.date_time",
            "TotalResultMapping").getResultList();
```

This way I can use my `@SqlResultSetMapping` and all is good.

Answer (score 0):

`SQLState` is 42601, this is a syntax error, according to [PosgreSQL's list of error codes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/errcodes-appendix.html).

Try removing the semicolon at the end of your Named native query declaration. Although you are using the semicolon when issuing your query on the database itself, the semicolon is NOT a part of the query itself.

So, this might work (not tested, but Oracle had similiar problems when you tried to add a semicolon to a plain JDBC query):

```
@NamedNativeQueries({@NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "Result.getTotal",
    query = "SELECT  date_time, GREATEST(sum(count_up - count_down) OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('day', peoplecounting.result.date_time) ORDER BY date_time),0) AS cum_amt FROM   peoplecounting.result order  BY date_time")})
```

Comment: Removing the semicolon did not change anything